# Moving WPProperties into different categories in custom WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, data-view-web-part, data-form-web-part

I'm working on a web part that thematically makes sense to have the `XSL Link` property in a custom category I created `Visual Settings` that provides new `WPProperties` for things like the CSS page and which Javascript file to attach to the web part. In this sense, it makes sense for us to move that property out of `Miscellanous` and into this custom category.

I thought it would be just as simple as writting over the property in my code-behind, but that doesn't seem to be the case (it breaks the webpart when I do that). Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you're inheriting from a Web Part which has XSLLink in the Category Miscellanous and you want to move it to Visual Settings.

You should be able to do that like this:

```
[WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebDisplayName("XSL Link")]
[WebDescription("Link to XSLT")]
[Category("Visual Settings")]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public new string XSLLink
{
  get { return base.XSLLink; }
  set { base.XSLLink= value; }
}
```

Comment: The line in the .webpart file has no influence. Is your new propery the exact same spelling and casing as the old?

Comment: Yes, and in fact if you change one it changes the other. It was strange to see me delete the value in the original `XSLLink` property only to have the value deleted in the new property!